# Start the GridView Elements from the right

Tags: android, gridview

I am making an app where i want the gridview to be filled from the right to the left "to use it for right to left languages", i tried to make the gridView gravity set to right but it didn't work ... my gridview layout is below.

Thanks in advance

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/show_info"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/channel_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best guess is to copy the code from the [GridView source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/GridView.java#GridView) and change the measuring/layouting to use right to left.

**UPDATE:** The layout direction for views was only introduced in API Level 17 (4.2).
If you compare GridView.java in [4.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/widget/GridView.java#GridView.makeRow%28int%2Cint%2Cboolean%29) and [4.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/widget/GridView.java#GridView.makeRow%28int%2Cint%2Cboolean%29), you can see that for example in the method `makeRow()`, the layoutDirection is taken into account since 4.2, so that should work!

Did you try to execute your code with `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` on API Level 17 ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think GridView was designed having languages in mind. It is more of a visual component for arranging thumbnail images.

You could solve that problem by modifying your adapter and letting it reverse the order of each item per row. However, you'd need to tell your adapter the amount of items per row for making that work.

On top of that if the last row has less items than possible, then you need to introduce empty dummy items for filling up the left.

Comment: Actually, it does take `layoutDirection` into account as of 4.2. I updated my answer with some additional links to the source.

Comment: This was a good hint, thanks. In my app the gridView has a fixed number of columns and this way I can simulate the rtl direction.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this. Have your GridView in your layout file have the following attribute

```
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_grid_right_to_left"
```

Create an `anim` folder wherein you add the `layout_grid_right_to_left.xml` with cotents

```
<gridLayoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:columnDelay="0.5"
    android:directionPriority="row"
    android:direction="right_to_left"
    android:animation="@anim/fade" />
```

Also add `fade.xml` in the same `anim` folder with contents

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

These are just for your reference. Please feel free to add/remove attributes that suit your needs/requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

It is usually for text and I don't know what's the effect on a gridView. ([ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3alayoutDirection))

Another thing to try is

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

But it won't work if you need to order the items top-down and right-to-left  ([ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3astackFromBottom))

Comment: stackFromBottom was the first thing i was thinking about, but it didnt help.

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layoutDirection' in package 'android'

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for your gridview and all of its items in XML :

```
 android:rotationY="180"
```

You can also use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`. It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a silly way to do this but it's work perfectly.

just make `android:ScaleX=-1` in gridview and in your item container(your custom view for grid view cells), so your layout become start from Right to Left!

hope this help